# Save a section of video from UIImagePickerController programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

I'm trying to work out how to programmatically edit the video data I get back from UIImagePickerController.

During the recording of this video I'm going to be listening out for interesting events and logging their time, then when the video is finished, I want to be able to cut out 10 second clips at these times and save them as individual videos.

You can do this with the editing controls, so I assume it is possible programmatically too.

So far I just have the code below getting the video data and I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 

if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || 
    [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) { // movie != video
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFMPEG library](https://github.com/jgh-/FFmpeg-for-iOS) cut video into pieces.

Perfectly for your requirement.